# Test panoramio result

Tags: api, jquery, panoramio

I`m using panoramio api to show some pictures about a destination. Unfortuanatly for some destinations they dont have any images.

How could i test if panoramio doesnt have any results so i can display something else.

I tried replacing it usig livequery:

```
$('#div_attr_ex_photo').find('.panoramio-wapi-empty-img').livequery(function(){
    //replace panoramio with something
})
```

This work, but only if i click, or press a button ( probably when any event occures ). Can`t imagine why...

Any other method that does the job is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple just go to panoramio website and then open World Map from panoramio website.Then go to specified location whichs latitude and longitude required.

Then you found latitude and longitude in address bar for example in this address.

http://www.panoramio.com/map#lt=32.739485&ln=70.491211&z=9&k=1&a=1&tab=1&pl=all

lt=32.739485 =>latitude
ln=70.491211 =>longitude

this Panoramio JavaScript API widget create a bounding box around a lat/long pair and then returning all photos with in those bounds.

Another type of Panoramio JavaScript API widget in which you can also change background color with [example and code is here](http://codespk.blogspot.com/2013/10/panoramio-javascript-api-widget-example.html).

It does not show in composing mood.It show after publishing.

```
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: center;" trbidi="on">
<script src="https://ssl.panoramio.com/wapi/wapi.js?v=1&amp;hl=en"></script>
<div id="wapiblock" style="float: right; margin: 10px 15px"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myRequest = {
  'tag': 'kahna',
  'rect': {'sw': {'lat': -30, 'lng': 10.5}, 'ne': {'lat': 50.5, 'lng': 30}}
};
  var myOptions = {
  'width': 300,
  'height': 200
};
var wapiblock = document.getElementById('wapiblock');
var photo_widget = new panoramio.PhotoWidget('wapiblock', myRequest, myOptions);
photo_widget.setPosition(0);
</script>
</div>
```